# Telerik RadEditor Component 'RadFileExplorer1_ajaxLoadingPanel' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have two sites. Both are almost identical except for the database they are connected to. Both use telerik RadEditor, however one has now stopped the upload buttons on the file manager and is giving me the following error:
***Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Component 'RadFileExplorer1_ajaxLoadingPanel' was not found.***

I've spent a long time trying to work out why this is happening but can't seem to find any information. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit:

Example code-

```
<telerik:RadEditor id="radEditor" runat="server" Height="800px" Width="100%" ContentFilters="None"
                            OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad">
            <Content>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AppSettingManager.GetInstance.RADEditorSettings.ConfigureEditor(RADEditorSettings.EditorType.Content, radEditor, "pathHere", css);
}


public void ConfigureEditor(EditorType type, Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor editor, string contentFolder, List<string> cssPaths)
    {
        this.ConfigureEditor(type, editor, cssPaths , 0 , 0);

        string[] contentEditPath = new string[2];

        contentEditPath[0] = this.ContentPath + contentFolder;
        contentEditPath[1] = this.LibraryPath;

        editor.ImageManager.MaxUploadFileSize = this.MaxImageSize;
        editor.ImageManager.SearchPatterns = this.ImageExtensions;
        editor.ImageManager.UploadPaths = contentEditPath;
        editor.ImageManager.DeletePaths = contentEditPath;
        editor.ImageManager.ViewPaths = contentEditPath;

        editor.DocumentManager.MaxUploadFileSize = this.MaxDocumentSize;
        editor.DocumentManager.SearchPatterns = this.DocumentExtensions;
        editor.DocumentManager.UploadPaths = contentEditPath;
        editor.DocumentManager.DeletePaths = contentEditPath;
        editor.DocumentManager.ViewPaths = contentEditPath;

        string[] templatePath = new string[] { this.TemplatesPath };

        editor.TemplateManager.SearchPatterns = this.TemplateExtensions;

        editor.TemplateManager.ViewPaths = templatePath;

        Telerik.Web.UI.EditorModule WebContentWordCountModule = new Telerik.Web.UI.EditorModule();
        WebContentWordCountModule.Name = "Module";
        editor.Modules.Add(WebContentWordCountModule);

        var script = new HtmlGenericControl();
        script.TagName = "script";
        script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
        script.Attributes.Add("src", script.ResolveUrl("~/Module.js"));
        editor.Controls.Add(script);

        if (ConvertToXhtml)
            editor.ContentFilters = Telerik.Web.UI.EditorFilters.ConvertToXhtml;

        editor.ContentAreaMode = Telerik.Web.UI.EditorContentAreaMode.Iframe;
    }
```

Comment: This looks to be related to RadFileExplorer, not RadEditor. Please post the markup and code behind related to this control for the offending page.

Comment: It's global. It is happening to every single RadEditor control on the site. But I will post an example of one.

Comment: Two sites are on the same server? As in they share the GAC? Did you compare the bin folders/web.configs to verify all assemblies exist in both places and/or are referencing the same assembly locations?

Comment: Both web configs are identical bar the DB connection string. Both bins are identical. Both run the same release. Both match on everything. This is why its so bizarre.

Comment: Again, I don't see markup or code referencing RadFileExplorer1. Do you see a similar exception related to controls in the provided markup/code behind? If so, please provide that exception and not an unrelated message.

Comment: There is no control called RadFileExplorer1 in the entire solution. I presume its in the Telerik dll? The only exception i get is when I inspect the site through chromes inspection tool and the error only occurs when I open up the upload manager off the radeditor.

Comment: Please post the full markup of your page so we can see what other controls you may be using.

Comment: Thats all thats on the page at the moment. no other controls. Just the radeditor.

Comment: Confirm the UploadPaths setting is correct. Try removing the custom module.js script that you inject in the editor. Ensure your page has valid markup. Ensure you don't have  <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" /> in your web.config as it can break AJAX.